# Powershell Add Additional Owner to AD Group

Tags: powershell

How to add additional owner to a AD group using Powershell?

I tried the code below, but I got the error "A referral was returned from the server"

Set-ADGroup -Identity “ADGroup” -ManagedBy "distinguishedName"

Comment: Try running powershell elevated

Comment: I tried to run as administrator, but still got the same error.

Comment: You are surrounding the identity of the group with curly quotes. Try using straight quotes or none at all. The Identity should be an ADGroup object, a SamAccountName, a GUID or the group SID. Other possible explanations may be that you have to specify admin credentials with parameter `-Credential` or even the DC you want to target with parameter `-Server`

Comment: Hi, I tried with Set-ADGroup -Identity ADGroup-ManagedBy " distinguishedName" -Server "Domain.XX.net", but got the error Set-ADGroup : Unable to contact the server. How can I verify the server or if the syntax is wrong?